# список пользователей и имени компьютеров AD и C#

Tags: c#, active-directory

Подскажите как можно вывести список пользователей и имя компьютера данного пользователя из AD с помощью c#. Получается только по отдельности выгрузить.

Comment: Ну и выгружайте отдельно. Если что -- то вообще-то никто не запрещает по умолчанию domain\user заходить с любой машины домена. И, кстати, было бы неплохо прикрепить в вопрос код, которым вы получаете списки пользователей и имя компьютера, а то мне кажется, что вы словами не совсем то описываете, что у вас в коде. Ну или точнее -- можно неправильно понять ваше объяснение. А вот код -- это будет однозначно.

Comment: Насколько я помню, в AD нет такого понятия как "компьютеры данного пользователя". Если ничего не изменилось в последнее время, то есть только история "логонов" юзера на доменные ПК. События "логонов" пишутся на контроллере домена в категорию `Windows Logs -> Security`. В подробностях события есть ip адрес хоста, с которого происходила попытка. Так что вам скорее всего нужно собирать информацию из этих логов.